# How to update existing Polyline in android mapbox?

Tags: android, mapbox

In map when I will click marker I will get poly line and distance. Again when I click another marker in map I will get a new Line but when I click the 2nd marker I need to update that poly line, no need to add multiple polylines.

Comment: you'll draw the polyline from same starting point??

Answer (score 3):

Latest Mapbox SDK has added an **updatePolyline()** method. It can be used to update your polyline. It was not present in older versions.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a reference. I just found it while I was coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this to add a polyline :

```
Polyline mPolyline = this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().....);
```

and then to remove simply call :

```
mPolyline.remove();
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: yeah i tried this but it will removing only i want to update

Comment: and after removing you create a new polyline with your new data

Comment: then provide new lat/lng to draw a new polyline